# I don't want the keyboard to display for my Text field in Flutter

Tags: flutter, input, text, field, calculator

I'm building a calculator and for that I want a text field in flutter which will just give me a space where I can type but using the on screen button I have created. I don't want the keyboard to pop up I just want the cursor so that the user can edit the given text anyway possible
How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

to hide keyboard and keep the cursor visible, set readOnly to true and showCursor to true

here how :-

```
TextFormField(
showCursor: true,
readOnly: true),
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a TextField, just use text and update the string of the text on each tap of the button. You can do that using StatefulWidget, it's simple. I did that.

Comment: Hey thank you for this, but I want to use the cursor functionality. Like if I place the cursor any where in the text I should be able to edit at that particular place. Any suggestions for this ?

Comment: You may try with a TextField where the keyboard is disabled and update controller text dynamically with string.